# How to use regular expressions in php to extract data like this?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code in php to extract username, password and email:

```
$subject = "fjcljt # 123456789 # chengyong702@126.com";
$pattern2 = '/^(\w+\ # ){2}?\w+ ?/';
preg_match($pattern2, $subject, $matches);
```

but the returned result using print_r is `Array ( [0] => fjcljt # 123456789 # chengyong702 [1] => 123456789 # )`

What am I doing wrong with preg_match here?

Comment: If you just want to separate username password and email in array then try explode(' # ', $subject);

Comment: Would pattern "any number of alphanum" for the username, "any non-hash for the password", and "any alphanum, @, any alnum, period, any alnum" work for you?  (alnum is alpha-numeric, fyi)

Answer (score 4):

if " # " delimits your values...no need for regex at all...

```
$subject = "fjcljt # 123456789 # chengyong702@126.com";
$subject = array_map('trim',explode("#",$subject));
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `preg_match` captures the entire string in `[0]`, and then each captured group in `[i]`. A captured group is denoted by the brackets in your `$pattern2`. Since there's only one set of brackets, there's only one captured group.

Even though your pattern matches twice, only the latest match is stored group 1, being `123456789 #` (overriding the `fjcljt #`).

To get explicit groups you have to write the captured groups in your regex explicitly as opposed to with the `{2}`:

```
$pattern2 = '/^(\w+\ # )(\w+\ # )\w+ ?/';
```

Then your return array will have `[1]` bein `fjcljt #` and `[2] being 1123456789 #`.

Comment: I thought this expression inspired by your help '/^(\w+(?= # ))(\w+(?= # ))([\w@.]+(?= ?)$/' would remove " # ", but actually it did not, what the new expression would be like if i want to remove " # " from the matched results?

Comment: try `/^(\w+)\ # (\w+)\ # ([@\w]+) ?/`, the brackets in my solution surround the # and space so they are included in the matches. To not have them, don't include them in the brackets. @CrayonViolent's answer is best though!

Answer (score 1):

```
list($username, $password, $email) = explode(' # ', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using explode instead of regex. regular expression use more resources.

> $data = explode('#','fjcljt # 123456789 # chengyong702@126.com');

then you can access data like below:

> $data[0]; //username
>   $data[1];  //password
>   $data[2];  //email

**EDIT**
for whitespace use delimiter like below:

> " # "

Comment: doesn't account for whitespace

Answer (score 0):

It's two things here. First you are using a quantifier `{2}` on a match group `(..)`. What happens is that you only get the last of the two matches as result group `[1]`. If you wanted to get both numbers/words separately, you have to expand the regex.

The second problem is that `\w+` does not include `@`. So you only get half the email.

```
$pattern2 = '/^(\w+) # (\w+) # ([\w@.]+)/';
```

Might be what you wanted.

Comment: I thought this expression inspired by your help '/^(\w+(?= # ))(\w+(?= # ))([\w@.]+(?= ?)$/' would remove " # ", but actually it did not, what the new expression would be like if i want to remove " # " from the matched results?

Comment: You can't remove. Truncating the `[0]` match group is possible by appending a `\K` to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the F bomb your trying to do, however if your trying to get login credentials you could try something like this

```
if(preg_match('/^.*\@.*$/i', $type_of_login) > 0)
{
$request = User::get_by_email($type_of_login);
}
else
{
   //get by username or whatevers....
}


//then extract the password!!
```